# Error when including e-mail when using the els-cas Elsevier template

Tags: errors, titles, els-cas

When I try to include my e-mail or an URL when using the `cas-sc` class I get an error with `\maketitle`. Here's my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{detect-all}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\shorttitle{An intelligent modular approach based on deep learning for forecasting}
\shortauthors{Ghulam Hafeez et al.}
%\begin{frontmatter}

\title [mode = title]{An intelligent modular approach based on deep learning for electric load forecasting in smart grid}
\author[1,2]{Ghulam Hafeez}%[orcid=0000-0002-9398-9414]
\author[1]{Nadeem Javaid*}
%\author[3]{Noor Islam}
%\author[1]{Khurram Saleem Alimgeer}
%\author[1]{Ammar Ali}
%\author[4]{Muhammad Riaz}
%\author[2]{Muhammad Usman}

\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cormark[1]
\ead{nadeemjavaidqau@gmail.com}
\ead[URL]{www.njavaid.com}
\address[1]{COMSATS University Islamabad, Islamabad 44000, Pakistan}
\address[2]{University of Engineering and Technology, Mardan 23200, Pakistan}
%\address[3]{CECOS University of IT \& Emerging Sciences, Peshawar 25124, Pakistan}
%\address[4]{Wah Engineering College, University of Wah, Wah Cantt 47070, Pakistan}
%and Khurram Saleem Alimgeer$^1$


\begin{abstract}[S U M M A R Y]
Short term load forecasting strategy is useful in the decision making of industrial, commercial and residential {smart grid (SG)} applications. Thus, several forecasting strategies have been proposed in the literature starting from legacy time series to contemporary data analytic models. CNN(210 seconds)\\
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Short term load forecasting;competition-2012.
\end{keywords}
\maketitle
\section{introduction}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `els-cas` classes use a set of thumbnails for email, URL, Facebook, etc. (because it's apparently very common to provide a link to your Facebook in scientific articles), but it does not put these thumbnails in a path searched by TeX. You have two options:

1. Disable the thumbnails. Add this code to your preamble (before using `\maketitle`) to disable thumbnails:

   ```latex
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \keys_set:nn { stm / mktitle } { nologo }
   \ExplSyntaxOff
   ```
2. Put the thumbnails in your working directory. Go to `$TEXMFROOT/texmf-dist/doc/latex/els-cas-templates` and copy the `thumbnails` folder to the folder where you have your main `.tex` file.

   - For Windows/MiKTeX users, usually `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\els-cas-templates`.
   - For Linux/TeXLive users, usually `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/texmf-dist/doc/latex/els-cas-templates` (Vanilla) or `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/els-cas-templates` (Package).

---

Also, you have to `\usepackage{natbib}` in your code, otherwise the class will throw another error.

Comment: It still generates error, please help

Comment: @GhulamHafeez What error? Which of the options above did you try? What is the error message?

Comment: The error still exists after incorporating your suggestions. @Phelype Oleinik

Comment: I have tried the first option \ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_set:nn { stm / mktitle } { nologo }
\ExplSyntaxOff \. And i have also used \usepackage{natbib}.

Comment: @GhulamHafeez In my computer it works fine. Can you please show the code which you used and the complete `.log` file?

Comment: It gives an error like \maketitle. However, when I comment \maketitle the file is executed without title, author name, and affiliation.

Comment: In which manner I will share you the complete file

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik . Let me know, How I send you the .log file through email?

Comment: @GhulamHafeez You can upload it to http://pastebin.com or any other file hosting service you prefer (Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik your first suggestion just saved my bacon, thanks!