# \tnotemark and \cormark not appearing next to title or author when using cas-dc

Tags: footnotes, titles, author, els-cas

## Background

I recently switched over a publication I am working on from `elsarticle` class to `cas-dc` in line with the journal's publishing recommendations,

### `elsarticle`

In `elsarticle` you might use something like the following ([from here](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/56843/elsdoc-1.pdf)) to get a note to appear on the title:

```
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1,t2}}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is the results of the research project funded by the National Science Foundation.}
\tnotetext[t2]{The second title footnote which is a longer text matter to fill through the whole text width and over flow into another line in the footnotes area of the first page.}
```

### `cas-dc`

However according to [documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates/doc/elsdoc-cas.pdf) this has changed to something like this:

```
\title [mode = title]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title}
\tnotemark[1,2]
\tnotetext[1]{This document is the results of the research project funded by the National Science Foundation.}
\tnotetext[2]{The second title footnote which is a longer text matter to fill through the whole text width and overflow in to another line in the footnotes area of the first page.}
```

I've been playing with the latter for awhile to no avail... the document compiles/typesets and I see the authors and title, and I *even* see the notes for the title and authors. However what I *do not* see is the star or asterisk next to the authors/title to indicate to whom the note belongs.

## MWE from the `cas-dc` documentation:

#### document result

[image: results title and authors]
[image: results footnotes]

#### code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{cas-dc} % can add 'twocolumn' option later

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}


\title[mode = title]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title}

\tnotemark[1,2]

\tnotetext[1]{This document is the results of the researchproject funded by the National Science Foundation.}
\tnotetext[2]{The second title footnote which is a longer textmatter to fill through the whole text width and overflow intoanother line in the footnotes area of the first page.}
\author[1,3]{CV Radhakrishnan}[type=editor,auid=000,bioid=1,prefix=Sir,role=Researcher,orcid=0000-0001-7511-2910]
\cormark[1]
\fnmark[1]
\ead{cvr_1@tug.org.in}
\ead[url]{www.cvr.cc, cvr@sayahna.org}

\credit{Conceptualization of this study, Methodology,Software}
\address[1]{Elsevier B.V., Radarweg 29, 1043 NX Amsterdam,The Netherlands}
\author[2,4]{Han Theh Thanh}[style=chinese]
\author[2,3]{CV Rajagopal}[%
    role=Co-ordinator,suffix=Jr,]
\fnmark[2]
\ead{cvr3@sayahna.org}
\ead[URL]{www.sayahna.org}
\credit{Data curation, Writing - Original draft preparation}
\address[2]{Sayahna Foundation, Jagathy, Trivandrum 695014,India}
\author[1,3]{Rishi T.}
\cormark[2]\fnmark[1,3]
\ead{rishi@stmdocs.in}
\ead[URL]{www.stmdocs.in}
\address[3]{STM Document Engineering Pvt Ltd., Mepukada,Malayinkil, Trivandrum 695571, India}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}
\cortext[cor2]{Principal corresponding author}
\fntext[fn1]{This is the first author footnote. but is commonto third author as well.}
\fntext[fn2]{Another author footnote, this is a very longfootnote and it should be a really long footnote. But thisfootnote is not yet sufficiently long enough to make two linesof footnote text.}

\nonumnote{This note has no numbers. In this work wedemonstrate $a_b$ the formation Y\_1 of a new type ofpolariton on the interface between a cuprous oxide slaband a polystyrene micro-sphere placed on the slab.}

\begin{abstract}[SUMMARY]
This template helps you to create a properly formatted\LaTeX\ manuscript.\noindent\texttt{\textbackslash begin{abstract}} \dots\texttt{\textbackslash end{abstract}} and\verb+\begin{keyword}+ \verb+...+ \verb+\end{keyword}+which contain the abstract and keywords respectively.Each keyword shall be separated by a \verb+\sep+ command.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
quadrupole exciton \sep polariton
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
\section{Intro}
Test
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

here is the log file as requested in the comments (sorry, if you know a better way of sharing this please let me know).

```
 *File List*
  cas-dc.cls    2020/03/14, 2.1: Formatting class for CAS double column article
s
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
 amsmath.sty    2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
   expl3.sty    2020-04-06 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-03-12 L3 backend support: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2020-03-06 L3 Experimental document command parser
etoolbox.sty    2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
 balance.sty    1999/02/23 4.3 (PWD)
booktabs.sty    2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
makecell.sty    2009/08/03 V0.1e Managing of Tab Column Heads and Cells
   array.sty    2019/08/31 v2.4l Tabular extension package (FMi)
multirow.sty    2019/05/31 v2.5 Span multiple rows of a table
colortbl.sty    2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)
   color.sty    1999/02/16
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 dcolumn.sty    2014/10/28 v1.06 decimal alignment package (DPC)
stfloats.sty    2017/03/27 v3.3 Improve float mechanism and baselineskip settin
gs
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
 xstring.sty    2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
footmisc.sty    2011/06/06 v5.5b a miscellany of footnote facilities
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
dvipsnam.def    2016/06/17 v3.0m Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
  svgnam.def    2016/05/11 v2.12 Predefined colors according to SVG 1.1 (UK)
hyperref.sty    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hypertext links for LaTeX
 ltxcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.24 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
pdftexcmds.sty    2019/11/24 v0.31 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2019/11/29 v3.13 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  bitset.sty    2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)
 hpdftex.def    2020/01/14 v7.00d Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
atveryend.sty    2019-12-11 v1.11 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
cas-common.sty    
moreverb.sty    2008/06/03 v2.3a `more' verbatim facilities
verbatim.sty    2019/11/10 v1.5r LaTeX2e package for verbatim enhancements
 wrapfig.sty    2003/01/31  v 3.6
 fontenc.sty
    stix.sty    2018/04/17 v1.1.3-latex STIX fonts support package
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
inconsolata.sty    2019/05/17 v1.12
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
geometry.sty    2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
geometry.cfg
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
 ls1stix.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX LS1 font definitions
 ls2stix.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX LS2 font definitions
  t1stix.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX T1 font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
 nameref.sty    2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
refcount.sty    2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
gettitlestring.sty    2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
 upquote.sty    2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verbat
im
ls1stixscr.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX script LS1 font definitions
ls2stixex.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX extentions LS2 font definitions
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ls1stixfrak.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX fraktur LS1 font definitions
ls1stixbb.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX blackboard LS1 font definitions
ls2stixcal.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX calligraphic LS2 font definitions

ls1stixsf.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX sans-serif LS1 font definitions
ls2stixtt.fd    2015/04/17 v1.1.2-latex STIX typewriter LS2 font definitions
untitled-9.abs
   t1zi4.fd    2018/01/14 T1/zi4 (Inconsolata)
  t1cmss.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: If I compile your example I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/erfcs.png, which seems to have the right markers.  What TeX distribution/version are you using?  Can you please add `\listfiles` at the very top of your document, then send the `.log` output?

Comment: Hi @PhelypeOleinik, I edited my question to include the ```log``` output but the file was too large to add in its entirety, so I only added everything below ``` *File List*```. This is probably _extremely_ amateurish so if you know of a better/more preferred way of sharing the log file please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: No, the file list is exactly what I wanted (usually it's easier to ask for the entire log, but not this time :-).  Weird thing is that your packages are almost up-to-date, so it is weird to be a version problem (in fact, I tried with TeXLive 2019 and the output is the same: `els-cas` didn't change much since it was first released).  My first suggestion would be to update your TeX distribution, but my hopes on that aren't too high.  Anyway, try an update then paste the full log at https://pastebin.com/ (or similar) and send the link, please

Comment: Hi @PhelypeOleinik, so I updated everything (all packages including MikTex through the MikTex console) and pasted the logfile [here](https://pastebin.com/NQ1Qm1j2). Please let me know if I can provide any more information and thanks again for your help and quick responses! (EDIT: I should also add that I checked and the issue persisted despite the upgrades.)

Comment: Really strange.  Except for some minor hiccups (which should definitely _not_ do that to your document), the log on your and my machine are basically the same...  I have no clue what's going on.  _/Puts debugging hat on/_ Please add the following code right after the `\documentclass` line, compile, and send me the log again: `\ExplSyntaxOn \tl_gset:cx { processTmarks~code } { \exp_not:N \tracingall \exp_not:v { processTmarks~code } \exp_not:N \tracingnone } \ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: Hi @PhelypeOleinik, thanks for not giving up on me! And I certainly hope your _debugging hat_ is more effective than the _crawl under the desk and whimper hat_ that  I've had on this whole time. The new log after having added your code below ```\documentclass``` can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/sF2CyC1J). Thanks!

Comment: Also, I have seen this error once or twice while compiling/typesetting:

```
LaTeX Warning: File 'thumbnails/cas-email.jpeg' not found on input line 51.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'thumbnails/cas-email.jpeg' not found: using d
raft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.51 \maketitle
```

Could that be a potential culprit? It disappears if I simply re-compile/typeset.

Comment: Bah, I think I got it (hopefully no need to crawl under the desk ;-).  How many times did you run LaTeX on the document before taking the screenshot?  The markings on the title only appear after building the document the second time (also the `\tnotemark[1,2]` command doesn't work before `\begin{document}`).  Also make sure you don't clean then auxiliary files between runs (maybe if you're running the document from your editor or with `latexmk`, it is cleaning the `.aux` automatically (and incorrectly!)).  As for the thumbnails issue, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514678/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, ah ok so I can only run it once before the error I mentioned about the thumbnails prevents it from compiling so perhaps it was resetting every other time and not preserving the ```.aux``` file or something similar. I will fix that issue and then try and re-run. Thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, well that was super quick and it worked! If you want to just copy + paste that comment as an answer I'm more than happy to accept it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, sorry to bombard you but I need to submit a retraction ... while the code you suggested on the thumbnails and running 2x was sufficient for my MWE, for my actual code it still throws an error every other time I run such that it won't compile twice. The error is ```! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.``` right before ```\maketitle```. I saw [this here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471842/missing-inserted-for-ifnum-usepackage) but I've commented out most of my code and the issue persists. [Here](https://pastebin.com/H6ngfgJe) is a log file, thanks for any help!

Comment: With the `\ifnum` problem the `.log` won't help much (it helps with package version stuff, but not much with code errors).  Since it's a kind of a different problem, I'd suggest you mark this thread solved and ask a new question with a compilable example that raises that error.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, sounds good I will open another question and see what happens, thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik (and anyone else who persists in having issues with this): I have posted a new related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563084/error-missing-inserted-for-ifnum-with-cas-dc-class). Thanks to anyone who can provide help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is due to a series of unfortunate mishaps:

1. The `\tnotemark` command saves info to the `.aux` file to take effect on the next run, but it does *not* (it probably should) define that information to take effect on the current run.
2. `els-cas` requires some thumbnails, but does not install them somewhere TeX can see, so the document class raises an error almost by default (fixing this should solve the whole problem: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/514678/134574).
3. The error raised by the thumbnails prevents your document from building successfully, and apparently your LaTeX IDE/Editor sees that the LaTeX run failed and deletes the `.aux` file, so the data saved by `\tnotemark` disappears due to the thumbnail issue...